# Simple FFT with DSP on STM32F407VG: How to interpret results and clear noise

Tags: stm32, adc, fft

It's my first project with STM32 (board stm32f4-disc1). I'm trying to create a simple spectrum analyzer for analyzing a signal (400-7000Hz, 0-3000 mV). My goal is to catch an event when the signal is above 2000 mV in a certain range (for example 1000-2000Hz). So I tried to realize an FFT function with DSP library (using CubeIde).
https://github.com/arcticplural/simple_fft
Here is my project, where I have succeeded with some stuff but still have some issues.

## Description

1. DAC is generating for me a sin wave by DMA on TIM2 (84 MHz on APB1, PSC=0, and CP=2183, sin pattern array size=100) => signal freq = 380Hz.
2. ADC on TIM1 (PSC=2, CP=3695) => sampling freq = 46875Hz (but I'm not sure)
3. Every 200 ms UART on TIM3 (PSC=256, CP=65535) send data to PC (still not sure about this timer)
4. DAC PA4 is connected to ADC PA1. UART is connected to the PC. Data collected fine.

## Issues

I've got this result:

[image: result]

1. I've got a peak in the 7th range, where 4.5 kHz expected, not 380 Hz.
2. I've tried other freq for DAC (0/299 for 2.8kHz and 0/839 for 1kHz) it doesn't work at all.
3. I still don't understand how to use this offset value. There is still too much noise. Why there is a lot of noise on pure sine wave?

```
int offset = 30; //variable noisefloor offset    
for (int i=0; i<ADC_BUF_LEN/2; i=i+2) {
    freqs[freqpoint] = (int)(20*log10f(complexABS(fft_out_buf[i], fft_out_buf[i+1])))-offset;
    if (freqs[freqpoint]<0) freqs[freqpoint]=0;
    freqpoint++;
}
```

4. I want to get max voltage of each range instead of the magic values. Should I do IFFT for each fragment?

I probably made a lot of mistakes here, but I can't found any and have stuck.

**Edit:**
result fft array:

```
    resultarray[0] = (uint8_t)freqs[1]; //31-5Hz
    resultarray[1] = (uint8_t)freqs[3]; //63 Hz
    resultarray[2] = (uint8_t)freqs[5]; //125 Hz
    resultarray[3] = (uint8_t)freqs[11]; //250 Hz
    resultarray[4] = (uint8_t)freqs[22]; //500 Hz
    resultarray[5] = (uint8_t)freqs[44]; //1 kHz
    resultarray[6] = (uint8_t)freqs[104]; //2.8 kHz
    resultarray[7] = (uint8_t)freqs[197]; //4.5 kHz
    resultarray[8] = (uint8_t)freqs[393]; //9 kHz
    resultarray[9] = (uint8_t)freqs[655]; //15 lHz
```

Comment: Get your test signal on a speaker, pick it up with a PC and FFT it is something like audacity.  It's quite possible you're capturing artifacts of the synthesis process...

Comment: I've tried my signal with an oscilloscope - it's a pure wave here

Comment: No DAC generates a pure sine wave; you either have more filtering than you say here, or you've somehow observing a filtered version of your signal if your scope shows a pure sine wave.

Comment: You right about DAC generator, I've tried math sin instead fft_in_buf[i] = 1000.0f*arm_sin_f32(2*3.1415926f*50*i/1000)+1000; the result is even worse. It seems I just have a mistake in the code somewhere. I'm still in the wrong range anyway.

Comment: What is PSC and CP? Why are there so few points in your FFT spectrum (you'd need at least 128 points to find 380Hz back in the lowest bin)?
And then we also have the usual suspects: Did you apply an anti-alias filter? Did you consider windowing to avoid spectral leakage?

Comment: Prescaler and Counter Period for TIM connected. 1024 points in my spectrum result array. I've just started with this example https://github.com/YetAnotherElectronicsChannel/STM32_FFT_Spectrum_Analysis and don't know where to move now. I have no any additional stuff. Could you share with me some links about anti-alias filter and windowing?

Comment: Here's one from TI: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCeHOf4cJE0&ab_channel=TexasInstruments